# How to make safe SELECT from sqlite3 DB in Python passing table name as parameter?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

folks.
I'm trying to figure out how to safely pass table name as parameter in SQL request from sqlite3 DB using aiosqlite in Python 3.9.

Request like this:

```
t = '2c2c33d6-6eb2-4040-959f-08821942e1af'
cursor = await dbconn.execute("""SELECT obstmstmp FROM '{}' ORDER BY obstmstmp DESC LIMIT 1;""".format(t))
obstmstmp = (await cursor.fetchone())[0]
```

do work, but may be prone to SQL injection. Even in this particular case uuid's come from the DB itself and not from user, I'm still wondering how to safely pass **table name** as parameter.

I have tried something like this:

```
t = '2c2c33d6-6eb2-4040-959f-08821942e1af'
cursor = await dbconn.execute("""SELECT obstmstmp FROM '?' ORDER BY obstmstmp DESC LIMIT 1;""", (t, ))
obstmstmp = (await cursor.fetchone())[0]
```

but it seems that `?` is not recognized, resulting in `no such table: ?` exception.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen, you can't dynamically bind object names (a table name in this case), only values), so you'll probably need to resort to some string concatenation.

One approach could be try and sanitize the table yourself:

```py
if "'" in t:
    raise ValueError('hacking attempt')
```

A slightly stronger approach may be to check that the input is a valid UUID:

```py
from uuid import UUID
UUID(t) # Will raise a ValueError if t isn't a valid UUID
```